# Drupal: How to display part of an author's profile in a node

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system, drupal-themes

I have been trying to do display a custom field I created in the manage fields section of user accounts for nodes in addition to the profile page. The problem I am having with this code is that it will display the first field it finds and display that for every user, not the field for that particular user.
And ideas? I believe it's finding the first value in the array and not the value for the particular user in the array.

Here is m setup so far:
Added this to my template.php of my theme:

```
function mythemename_preprocess_node(&$vars) {

global $user;
  $user = user_load($user->uid); // Make sure the user object is fully loaded
  $team = field_get_items('user', $user, 'field_team');
  if ($team) {
    $vars['field_team'] = $team[0]['value'];
  }
}
```

Then, added this to my node.tpl.php in order to display it on nodes.

```
if (isset($field_team) && !empty($field_team)) :
  echo '$field_team.'</div>';
endif;
```

**UPDATE:** 
Found my own aswer here:
http://drupal.org/node/1194506

Code used:

```
<?php
  $node_author = user_load($node->uid);
  print ($node_author->roles[3]);
  print ($node_author->field_biography['und'][0]['value']);
?>
```

Comment: Not sure I fully understood your intention, but the `global $user;` variable refers to the user doing the request (either a logged in known user, or the anonymous user), _not_ to the node author. For that, you'd need to do a `user_load($vars['node']->uid)`.

Comment: You should turn your Update findings into an answer to your own question, and later on accept it, so that the question does not stay open as 'unanswered'.

Comment: Henrik, thanks. New to the exchange here, I tried and it said I had to wait 8 hrs, so I updated the question for others to see. I guess I can come back in 8 hrs and answer.

Comment: @kidA: I see - sorry to ask for stuff you already tried. I did not know about the current timing constraints for 'self answering' :/

Answer (score 2):

You can use drupal's 'Author Pane' module for that. Try this:

http://drupal.org/project/author_pane